# Adding Items to JList from textField

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, textbox, jlist

I am trying to add information from a textbox into jlist though i doesnt seem to work.

I initialize the JList here:

```
    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setColumns(10);

    btnAdd = new JButton("Add");

    JButton btnRun = new JButton("Run");

    listIn = new JList();
    listIn.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
```

Then add an action to a button to get the text from the textField

```
    btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            listIn.addElement(textField.getText());  //This is what i assume it has to be , but it does not recognize the method "addElement"
        }
    });
```

Am i initializing the JList wrong ?

Comment: Please provide a complete runnable example [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), so we can see what's wrong.

Comment: When in doubt, check [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html).  Effective Java development requires frequent use of the javadocs.  (I keep a local copy on every machine where I do development.)

Answer (score 3):

Define proper list model to add elements

```
DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
JList<String> listIn = new JList<>( model );
```

And then add it in the action

```
model.addElement(textField.getText());
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html).

The `ListDemo` is a working example that shows you how to both "add" and "remove" items from a JList. It will also show you how to better structure your code so the GUI is created on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).

Keep a link to the tutorial handy for all the Swing basics.